# Is there a quick way to build a path from a list of parts other than using ifs?

Tags: c#, string

I need to build a filepath based on a number of elements that may or may not exist, and I'm struggling to think of a way I can simply the code syntax without using a load of if statements.

Say I have a method that does the below

```
public string BuildPath(string serialNumber, string path, string filename) {  
    string path = "";
    if(String.isNullorWhitespace(path) {
        path = serialNumber + "/" + filename;
    }
    else {
        path = serialNumber + "/" + path + "/" + filename;
    }
}
```

The complexity here comes from the fact that if path is empty or null, I only require a single `/` character in the final path, if I don't do this properly the path won't be valid.

Comment: I'm confused.  In the above code the else will _never_ run.

Comment: the local variable path is needed to be renamed

Answer (score 2):

I am hoping that your code has a typo in it, because as its currently written there will be no `else` runs...

I like a LINQ/params approach:

```
public string BuildPath(params string[] input) 
{  
    return string.Join('/', input.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(x)));
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
BuildPath("justone"); // justone
BuildPath("missing", "", "one"); // missing/one
BuildPath("some", "path", "to", "somewhere"); // some/path/to/somewhere
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a list and `Join` them on slash:

```
var pathList = new List<string>{serialNumber, path, filename};
pathList = pathList.RemoveAll(i => String.IsNullOrEmpty(i));
return String.Join('/', pathList);
```

Comment: I'm assuming (dangerous) that that line where he always sets path to nothing is a mistake...

Comment: Yeah thats kinda what I am assuming too (hopefully haha)

Comment: Yes, that's a mistake due to quick typing hahah.

Answer (score 0):

Try change the parameter to `List<string>` type and change the like this:

```
public string BuildPath(List<string> urlParts) {  
    return string.join("/", urlParts);
}
```

join method of string handles null.

Comment: This does not account for the logic in OP's code though, so this will _not_ do the same thing.

Comment: Plus there is no need to change the parameters.  A simple `params[] string` would not break backwards compatibility

Comment: then you can try ternary operator to simplify the code